# Minecraft 1.14.4 villager won't collect 8 seed packs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I really want to have an automatic wheat farm using villagers on my survival world, but they need to have their inventory full os wheat seeds. The problem is that when I try to give than that 8 packs, they just take 4. If I throw any wheat after that, they'll take too!

Somebody know why this is happening, and how to fix it (or another way to build an automatic wheat farm)?

Here you can see (I just spawned this villager seconds before GIF starts):

[image: demo]

Villagers just collects 4 seed packs, and 4 wheat packs. I see everyone's villagers collecting 8 packs (form the same item), so what's happening?

I'm on Minecraft 1.14.4.

Comment: They probably already have some in their inventory.

Comment: I just spawned that villager few seconds before the gif starts. I'll update my question. Thanks, anyways! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Villagers currently can hold only 4 stacks of items of one kind. You can fill the remaining 4 slots of the villager's inventory with wheat, or leave them empty so the villager will fill them with picked wheat on his own. As long as there are no other plantable items (seeds/potatoes/carrots) within the villager's reach, the remaining space is not a problem; it may delay the time the farm starts "operating at full capacity" but won't prevent it from working.

Comment: But than they’ll make bread to give to each other, right? Even with the right number of beds.

Comment: @Brhaka: They don't craft bread currently (as of 1.14.4; it's a bug). They will pick wheat that's mature and replant seeds, and once they have 4 stacks of wheat they'll leave the wheat on the ground to be picked by a collection system (minecart with hopper). In case of other crops there's a way to entice the villager to throw the food items at another and *miss*, dropping them into a hopper.

Comment: Ok. Good to know that they're not going to craft. Thank you!

Comment: @Brhaka Note this is pretty high on the list of bugs to fix.

Comment: Thanks! I didn’t knew about that. But collecting just 4 packs of the same item is such a normal behavior? Because I’m pretty sure players on 1.14.2 gave than 8 packs.

Comment: @Brhaka: That is a new feature, introduced in 3. or .4. I don't recall the exact rationale but it counters some kind of undesired behavior connected with villagers filling their inventories with 1 type of item.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again SF!!! You really helped me. :)